# ZF2 mail error Too many RSET commands

Tags: zend-framework2, smtp

I have to send a lot of emails distributed over the whole day with ZF2 and I'm using Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp. I have the mails in a queue table and once a minute I want to send them. Everything works fine until 5th email, where I receive an error : `Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException
 4.7.0 Too many RSET commands; closing connection`
I guess this is coming from the smtp server. But why does ZF2-Smtp reset each message? I don't know where to start debugging the problem and if you need more informations just let me know. Thx for any help...

What I'm using is:

```
$transport = new SmtpTransport();
    $options = new SmtpOptions(array(
        'host' => $config['mail_options']['server'],
        'port' => $config['mail_options']['port'],
        'connection_class' => 'login',
        'connection_config' => array(
            'username' => $config['mail_options']['smtp_user'],
            'password' => $config['mail_options']['smtp_password'],
            'ssl' => $config['mail_options']['ssl'],
        ),
    ));
foreach ($queuedMails as $queuedMail) {
   $message = new Message();

            $message->addTo($data['to'])
                    ->addFrom($config['mail_options']['from'], $config['mail_options']['from_name'])
                    ->setSubject($data['subject'])
                    ->setBody(utf8_decode($data['body']))
                    ->setEncoding('utf-8');
$transport->setOptions($options);
            $transport->send($message);enter code here
}
```

Should I place the $transport into the foreach?

Comment: I think that that error rather is the response of the mailserver that doesn't like the way ZF sends multiple messages over 1 connection (ie, by sending an RSET between each mail). Could you try sending all mails over new connections to see whether that solves the issue?

Comment: Sending RSET is done to ensure that the connection is in a certain state. Now, the server indicates that it doesn't like to receive more than a certain amount of RSETs. Why this is the case is a question that can only be answered by the implementor of the server. The solution is to limit the number of messages sent over the same connection, I'd start with 1 connection, 1 mail as that's the most simple to implement.